# Print last name automatically

Tags: python

I want to print last name automatically when the first name has been entered.

```
first_name = ("ata","amina","aarifa")
last_name = ("gowani","rajani","gowani")
print ("enter your first name")
first_name = input()
print ("your last name  is", (last_name ))
```

Comment: Automatically means?

Comment: i means after user put his first name , program gets his last name and print with first name

Comment: How do you want to store your first names and last names? In a list? Can you give an example of expected input and expected output?

Comment: i am very new to python ,

Comment: first_name = ("ata","amina","aarifa")
last_name = ("gowani","rajani","gowani")
print ("enter your first name")
first_name = input()
print ("your last name  is", (last_name ))# how do i print last name of ata )

Comment: Use `dict` to map first to last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print last name based on your input. If it present on the list of first_name_list then take index and print from last_name_list with that index.

```
first_name_list = ("ata","amina","aarifa")
last_name_list = ("gowani","rajani","gowani")
print ("enter your first name")
first_name = input()
if first_name in first_name_list:
    index = first_name.index(first_name)
    last_name = last_name_list[index]
    print ("your last name  is", (last_name ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict that maps the first names to the last names by zipping the two lists and and passing the resulting sequence to the dict constructor:

```
first_name = ("ata","amina","aarifa")
last_name = ("gowani","rajani","gowani")
mapping = dict(zip(first_name, last_name))
print("enter your first name")
first_name = input()
try:
    print("your last name  is", mapping[first_name])
except KeyError:
    print("your name is not registered")
```

Comment: i do not understand this

Comment: except KeyError:
    print("your name is not registered")

Comment: This is so that your script would print a friendly error message when the first name that the user inputs does not match any of the items in the `first_name` list. The `KeyError` exception is raised when a given key does not exist in the dict.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)